# How do I import data from a SOAP API into SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, web-services, soap, integration

I would like to integrate my database with a 3rd party application. The application exposes a SOAP API, but how do I go about consuming this from SQL Server? Do I need to use some sort of middleware to accomplish this?

Oddly enough, there doesn't seem to be a lot of information online about how this should be done.

Comment: Have to explain this a bit more. Are you saying you want to do something like `select * from externalapp.externalinterface.someapi` from within sql? Seems like a poor architecture. You could go the CLI route and access via sql function calls, otherwise you would need to create an ODBC or OLEDB data source that translates the soap calls into standard database calls. Sounds like a world of pain!

Comment: I'm looking to pull information from a SOAP-based API, and store it in a temporary staging table so that it can be used for some reporting. Ideally, the service could also push new data into the table as it's added.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't try and embed this in sql server. You might find you can do it in SSIS, but speaking personally I would just write a small piece of c# code (or whatever language you like) that reads from your api and writes to you database.